# Check IP Blocking on Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows, networking, windows-server-2008, tomcat, ip-blocking

When I login to google webmaster tools, from last 5-6 days I am getting error regarding Google connectivity issue.

It says googlebot is not able to access the site.

When I set User agent in firefox as googlebot and access the site, it works preety well, so I concluded that something on my windows server 2008 is blocking.

I queries google and they say that might be googlebot IP is blocked by my server or firewall.

I tried to add the IP to my whitelist, but still the same issue.

Now its 7th day and I have tried everything that I knew. Or other possiblity is googlebot ip traffic is not blocked but diverted which does not look possible as my tomcat is listening port 80 and working fine.

Questions -

*** how to know if any Ips are blocked

*** Any tool which will mock googlebot correctly and fix it

Comment: Check your web server access log. Googlebot may be allowed in your firewall, but your application server might not serve content to googlebot. check for any 44 or 500 http status code.

Comment: If Tomcat is running http default and you can reach from the internet, this would seem like you have a firewall blocking this.  Check the logs on the host for Windows firewall perhaps? ModSecurity will block this by default, but you are not using Apache per notes.